# AntDesign TabPane min-height 100%

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, height, antd

Using Ant.Design Tabs https://ant.design/components/tabs/

How can I set styling on TabPane so that it's min-height is always 100% height of the window even when it's empty?

Below example should cover the window with color #F5F5F5

[image: Edit epic-flower-tg0g3]

Comment: How do you expect the window to look? And what did you try? You just posted an official example.

Comment: The window should expand 100% in height and not grow in height depending on the content within the TabPane. I have tried to applying css min-height to TabPane and applying a class to it but TabPane only gets bigger when you put more content in. I would like to make TabPane 100% in height with or without content in them.

Comment: so why min height and not max height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has worked for me.

```
<TabPane tab={tab.title} key={index}>
<Row>
  <Col style={{minHeight: "100vh", maxheight: "100vh"}}>
   Test
  </Col>
</Row>
</TabPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

So this has worked for me too

```
   <Tabs
      onChange={() => {
      console.log("oi");
      }}
      type="card"
      style={{ background: "blue", height: "100%" }}
   >
   <TabPane
      tab="Tab 1"
      key="1"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh", background: "red" }}
   >
      Content of Tab Pane 1
   </TabPane>
 </Tabs>
```