# How to force antd tabs to be full height even if no content (with React and styled components)

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

I have a react app that uses ant design and styled components and am trying to get antd tabs to render the full height available but setting height to 100% or min-height to 100% is not working, however if I set 100vh it works... but this (of course) does not give the result I want because the component I am trying to render is not the full height of the screen.

Does anyone have experience with ant design that might have a good trick? I've looked at some solutions here on stack overflow but they do not seem to work. One was to use a row and col ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546564/antdesign-tabpane-min-height-100)). I've also read through issues on github that suggest to target the specific antd classes like [this one](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/9622) but it also does not seem to work.

Finally, I have a [code sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/23hzu?file=/index.js) that I have taken directly from ant design's site and added a style prop to the TabPane, setting the height and background (just to be able to see the effect) if someone would like to fiddle with it.

Please chime in if you have experience and a definite solution or even a suggestion at this point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with `height : 100vh` property .with appropriate padding .

here is the code sandbox link for the same .

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-silence-d02qi?file=/index.js:2079-2088